Finding the value range using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
English is not my mother tongue so my English may sound weird.
When real numbers $x,y$ satisfies $\sin x+3 \sin y=1$,let $z=\cos x+3 \cos y$. Find the range of $z$.
I came across to this problem when studying vector.Let $\overrightarrow{P}=(\cos x, \sin x),\overrightarrow{Q}=(\cos y, \sin y), \overrightarrow{R}=(z, 1) $. Then $\overrightarrow{R}= \overrightarrow{P}+3 \overrightarrow{Q} $.
Therefore by considering the range of $P$ and $Q$,we get  $-\sqrt{15}\le z\le -\sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt{3}\le z\le\sqrt{15}$.
This is the correct range of $z$ .
Now when we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,we get
$z^2\le(\cos^2x+\sin^2y)(1^2+3^2)$.
And by using $\sin x+3 \sin y=1$, I got $-\sqrt{19}\le z\le\sqrt{19}$.
The reason I got the wronge range may be because I considered $\sin y$ as $-1\le \sin y \le 1$. How can I get the correct range using Cauchy inequality? Is it even possible?
